# My character is sliding, not playing animation (Unity3d, Animator, Blend Tree, Animation)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

Advanced sorry for bad english, My humanoid character is sliding, not playing animation, on it. Even animation plus character both are humanoid.
In inspector animation works fine on character, but during gameplay it slides. I am sharing Screen shots and little video clip, please have a look.
Video Link [Click here to see video, what actually happens](https://streamable.com/9b5ypq)
all values related to walk blend tree are correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Checking the following may help:
 * Is the BlendTree the active state while the character runs? This should be visible from the BaseLayer
 * The Shooting & AimOffset layers are not overriding the root & leg movement. It's easiest to check this by turning their weight to 0
 * The bone hierarchy for your character in the scene is the same as the expected bone hierarchy for the animation (e.g. the animator controller is not on a GameObject *containing* the bones, it's directly attached to the SkinnedMeshRenderer)

Comment: @normalcherie thank you so much, its help me a lot. Yes it was wight issue with layers. In my case only Aimoffset layer was culprit. Don't know how I miss that. You can answer this, I will Definity accept.

Comment: Hi, many users, including me, feel with you. Explaining downvotes is encouraged but disappointingly rarely done. However, you seem to have missed an intentional design decision: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote I.e. StackOverflow WANTS votes (up and down) and decided to protect voters from retaliation, by allowing anonymous voting. So users who vote anonymously are doing as allowed and appreciated, though doing it with explanation to help with improving would of course be even more appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the following may help:

- Is the BlendTree the active state while the character runs? This should be visible from the BaseLayer
- Are the Shooting & AimOffset layers are overriding the root & leg movement? It's easiest to check this by turning their weight to 0
- Is the bone hierarchy for your character in the scene is the same as the expected bone hierarchy for the animation? (e.g. the animator controller is not on a GameObject containing the bones, it's directly attached to the SkinnedMeshRenderer). This can also be checked by dragging the mesh gameobject from the scene into the animation preview window.

The animation system in Unity can be pretty fiddly, so when complex animations don't work it's usually helpful to confirm the basics are behaving correctly first before jumping into debugging the more complicated features.